# JavaFX - Correct Icon Size For All Screen Resolutions

Tags: javafx, icons, resolution

How I can set the size of the icons in my JavaFX application according to the available screen resolution.

At this moment I set the size manually, but for low resolution they are to big and for high resolution they are to small.

Edit:

I think the best way would to choose between different css files for screen resolution categories. Is this possible with JavaFX?

Answer (score 0):

You could, at the startup of your fx app, get the resolution (like this) :

```
Rectangle2D targetScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds()
```

and then set prefWidth and prefHeight in your icon `Control` instance accordingly (with a per-ratio logic), if it's indeed a javafx node you were talking about.

**EDIT** : About dynamic screen resolution change : You cannot explicitly add a listener to Screen's resolution change, AFAIK. However, you could add a listener to your main Stage background. It is very likely that it's width and height properties will be resized according to screen's resolution change, but yet has to be tested on your target OS. If you need for example an icon size that would be 1/20th of stage's height, you could do like :

```
Stage stage = ... //this is your app main stage
Glyph glyph = ... //this is your Icon, here it is for example from org.controlsfx.glyphfont
glyph.prefWidthProperty().bind(stage.heightProperty().divide(20));
glyph.prefHeightProperty().bind(stage.heightProperty().divide(20));
```

Comment: But when I change the screen resolution while the application is running, it will not change. Correct?

Comment: I edited my answer. But what is the Class you are using for this Icon ?